# Google Play BETA testing wrong supported Android version

Tags: android, google-play

I have just published my first Android app for BETA testing. The minimum required Android version is 4.4.x which is indicated in the AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
```

It seems supported devices are filtered out accordingly, but on the Google Play store page as says

> Required Android:
>   1.6 and up

This seems quite misleading. 
Is there a way to fix that?

**Update:**
This seems to be correct ones the app is published as a production version.

Comment: you trying to update your's existing app in beta testing?

Comment: No, I just published for the first time.